# Is it recommended to email a professor at other institution to work with him over the summer

Tags: research-undergraduate, international-students, internship, networking

I am currently an undergraduate in mathematics and physics and graduate student in applied mathematics in the US. I am looking for a research position/internship for the summer (somewhere other than my current institution). Is it recommended to cold-call or send emails asking professors or researchers at other institutions around the world for an opportunity to work with them? In what other way can I find a position for this summer?
I am specifically looking at institutions in the US, Europe, Japan, Taiwan and China.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just reach out with SHORT emails.  I would not expect too much reply since it is a cold call but "a shot on net is always a good play".  Mention a sentence or two to indicate you looked at their webpage or pubs and have an interest in their work.

In addition, try to send some inquiries (similar format) where have some connection (e.g. you mentioned friends had visited specific places in Italy, England).  Professors like to get some "pipeline".  (E.g. "we have had periodic Elbonia Uni students".) Just gives some slight familiarity for you/them and some feeling for them that they may get more positive experiences in future.  However, note that expectations for undergrad visitors is not high.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention a broad range of countries, I think you should first try to get information about the typical yearly schedule, because in some countries summer may be a busy period.

For instance, since a couple years, I've started to receive emails from random students asking to do a summer internship with me. But from June to July, I'm busy with exams, workshops and conferences, in August I'm on vacation, and in September I have again exams and conferences. So, I usually decline any request in that period. I know other European groups with a similar situation.

Comment: I would expect the professors I contact to notify me if that is the case since I have known of people going to England and Italy for summer internships. Do you have any recommendations of universities or other institutions where I could enquiry?